# jQuery - Register / unregister listener for element "document"

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listeners

I'll try to explain my problem. I'm using `mouseup` event listener so I can check whenever a click is performed and the target is not the desired element. This is the code I'm using:

```
function clickOutListener(element, callbackFunction){

    $(document).mouseup(function(e){

        if(!$(element).is(e.target) && $(element).has(e.target).length === 0) callbackFunction.call(this, null);

    });
}
```

As you can see, the event listener is bound to the global document element and the way to unbind the listener would be:

```
$(document).off("mouseup");
```

Here comes what I need to achieve. If I unbind `mouseup` listener it will affect the other elements which use this listener (dropdowns and other features). I must guess that everytime I'm registering a listener it's not overriding the previous defined listener but adding the defined target function.

How can I access the different defined target functions for the same listeners?

```
$(document).mouseup(funct1);
$(document).mouseup(funct2);
$(document).mouseup(funct3);
```

How would you unregister the registered listener just for "funct2"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seeing you are using jQuery, have a look at event namespacing, that might help ► https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can namespace your events when using the `.on()` syntax.

```
$(document).on('mouseup.myNamespace', function(e){ ... }
```

This allows you to remove events by namespace whilst leaving others in place.

```
$(document).off('mouseup.myNamespace');
```